# Error: Cannot find protocol declaration in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, protocols

I am getting an error when I am using a custom protocol.

**TKCalendarMonthView.h**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@protocol EventViewProtocol;

@interface TKCalendarMonthView : UIView <PSMonthSelectedDelegate, PSYearSelectedDelegate,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> {

    id <EventViewProtocol> __unsafe_unretained eventDelegate;

}

@property (nonatomic,unsafe_unretained) id <EventViewProtocol> eventDelegate;

@end

@protocol EventViewProtocol <NSObject>

- (void)navigateToEventView;

@end
```

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ELScrollView.h"
#import "TKCalendarMonthView.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, EventViewProtocol> //At this line I am getting the error as "Cannot find protocol declaration for EventViewProtocol"

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor* horizontalBgColor;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor* verticalBgColor;


@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a circular import reference. Change TKCalendarMonthView to this:

```
@class ViewController;
@protocol EventViewProtocol;

@interface TKCalendarMonthView : UIView <PSMonthSelectedDelegate, PSYearSelectedDelegate,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> {

    id <EventViewProtocol> __unsafe_unretained eventDelegate;

}

@property (nonatomic,unsafe_unretained) id <EventViewProtocol> eventDelegate;

@end

@protocol EventViewProtocol <NSObject>

- (void)navigateToEventView;

@end
```

Comment: what the circular import reference means?

Comment: In ViewController.h you `#import` TKCalendarMonthView.h, and in TKCalendarMonthView.h you `#import` ViewController.h - circular